# Smothed surface of object in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I generage meshes and gameobjects in scene in Unity3d. I set Standard Shader for materials. Why surface of game objects not smoothed (like stepwise): http://screencast.com/t/M2hxgkw5N.

Comment: Try in Edit-> Project Settings -> Quality, set the anti-aliasing to some 2x or 4x. Point being to find a compromise between quality and efficiency.

Comment: @fafase you could change your comment into an answer

Comment: Well, someone did with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are facing now is called Aliasing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

It occures in digital images due to they are made of pixels. In simple words if you want to draw a line that is not parallel to the width and height of the digital screen, process of Rasterisation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) will make this line look like you see your pipes in given by you reference image.

To fix this people invented Anti-aliasing, that - in simple words - make a transition beetween aliasing steps, making it looks more smooth.

Unity3D has builtin Anti-aliasing. You can turn it on in quality setings (as **fafase** has mantioned in comment):

[image]

Note that, Anti-aliasing is quite expensive and on mobile devices could be a big problem.